# TypeScript garbled characters with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, character-encoding, typescript

I've used Sublime Text and WebStorm, and now I am trying to use **Visual Studio** to code TypeScript.

But characters garble in new project as below:

Source code:

```
タグ
```

[image]

Evaluated string:

```
\u30BF\u30B0
```

I've never met this problem before start using **Visual Studio**. Why? What is different from Sublime Text and WebStorm?

[image]

Comment: So do you mean there a typescript file you worked on in Sublime Text and WebStrorm you worked on but, when you are opening same file in Visual Studio you are finding these ロゴ characters?

Comment: No, I am opening different file which generated when creating a new project by Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Due to a missing BOM header (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Go to advanced save options :

[image]

And save as UTF8.

Comment: Thank you answering. I already tried to add BOM and remove BOM, but both works wrong.

Comment: Which character encoding are you saving in? You should be choosing "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001"